# Can not add images after add background to audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I use below command to concat background to an audio file:

```
"ffmpeg" -i /path/to/image.png -i /path/to/audio.mp3 -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p /path/to/video-1.mp4 2>&1
```

Next, I use that command to add other images to created video:

```
"ffmpeg" -f concat -safe 0 -i /path/to/text.txt -i /path/to/video-1.mp4 /path/to/video-2.mp4 2>&1
```

Content of my text.txt file:

```
/path/to/img1.jpg
duration 6
/path/to/img2.jpg
duration 6
/path/to/img3.jpg
duration 6
/path/to/img4.jpg
duration 6
```

Obtained video display only background image. Other images have not been shown.

What are my wrong in these commands? And how to set the display position of other images in video? To display images by position, I use below command, but after it ran, my machine was crashed:

```
"ffmpeg" -f concat -safe 0 -i /path/to/text.txt -i /path/to/video-1.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=0:0, scale=640:640" /path/to/video-2.mp4 2>&1
```

> > Update:

I do follow order by below steps and got video with text and images, but the position is incorrect. I can't find any solution for custom:

```
"ffmpeg" -f concat -safe 0 -i /path/to/text.txt -i /path/to/audio.mp3 -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p /path/to/tmp-video-1.mp4 2>&1

"ffmpeg" -i /path/to/background.png -i /path/to/tmp-video-1.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" /path/to/tmp-video-2.mp4 2>&1

"ffmpeg" -i /path/to/tmp-video-2.mp4 -vf "[in]<define texts and duration>[out]" -codec:a copy /path/to/endvideo.mp4 2>&1
```

Please take a look my video: http://184.171.170.45/cron/tmp/funny-1489648654.mp4 
I tried to set overlay property in second command: `-640:0`, let images in horizontal center of background, but its not working

Comment: If you want to append more images, you need to use concat filter or add them to original text file. Make sure they have the same resolution.

Comment: I used txt file to store image paths as above. But its not displayed. May be its overlapped by background

Comment: In your last command, the order of the inputs should be reversed. But can't diagnose further without seeing log.

Comment: Please take a look my update, wait me for log @Mulvya

Comment: For center, overlay x should be `W/2`. BTW, you can perform all three steps in one command.

Comment: I tried with single command, and the machine crashed

Comment: What was the command?

Comment: its working perfectly. You save 3 days life of me. How to me bounty you as my thanks?